# How to build older version of glibc?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc

I want to build gcc-8.1.0 cross-compiler for ARM from sources, but with glibc 2.23 because of the backward compatibility with some other project I have.
I am building it on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

My host machine is amd64 architecture.

But during the building of glibc I get an error:
`` /tmp/ccs9D1VT.s: Error: `loc1@GLIBC_2.17' can't be versioned to common symbol 'loc1' ``
The tutorial I got instructions on how to build gcc is in the link: http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

Can somebody tell me why the glibc 2.23 won't be built from sources? 
Did anybody encounter this kind of problem before?

Comment: The almighty google suggests this is a known issue with building older glibc with newer binutils - see for example [glibc: add patch fixing the build with binutils 2.29](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/797471/)